# How to play a ONE song repeatedly by Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-media-player

There is a repeat button on the player but there is no `repeat current song only` button.

I want to repeat a specific song in a list but I cannot do it with Windows Media Player

Comment: Well, if you want to only repeat 1 song, why do you need other songs in the list? Remove all songs other than the one to be repeated? Or, create a few playlists if you need to move around different collections of songs (each playlist may have 1 or more songs)

Comment: I don't use WMP, so see if the last post on [this page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpromedia/thread/8277138a-a425-4acb-939b-ac21efff875a/) helps.

Comment: @DaveRook I have a playlist with favorite songs. Up to my mood, sometimes I just like to listen to one specific song only. It's just the normal need don't you think. Lots of player out there implement this feature.

Comment: I was also going to try out creating a playlist with the same song repeated but my library is borked and WMP keeps crashing my system. @NamG.VU are you looking for an answer or just want to rant about a feature WMP does not have.

Comment: Further to @BradPatton point, is there a reason you're trying to achieve this in WMP? I mean, if *"Lots of player out there implement this feature"*, then why not use one? -1

Comment: I love to use built-in player so I love to use WMP. I look for an answer and not rant about it. Please understand

Comment: If anyone is looking at this page regarding Media Player Classic instead of Windows Video Player (Google directed me here for such request), the answer is: at Media Player Classic, click on View menu, select Options, then Playing section (Reproducción), and tick the checkbox "Repeat loop" ("Repetir continuadamente"). Finally click "Apply" button.

Answer (score 7):

Create a playlist with a single song and repeat that.

or

Repeatedly drag the same song from the library to the playlist.

or

Use another media player.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on repeat mode, right-click the song that you want to repeat in WMP's library, and select **Play** (instead of **Play all**).

Comment: This does not work for me

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work? **Play** will create a playlist with that single song. Repeating the playlist will repeat just the single song.

Comment: I miss the part you said `that you want to repeat in WMP's library`. I do it from the playlist

Answer (score 2):

On: Windows Media Player - Sun Jun 14 2015 - 1507 edt

You want to repeat one song, continuously.

1. Get yourself to: View / Library

   There are 3 panes:
2. In the Left-pane: double-left-click on your CD.

   Its track list will appear in both other panes, and 
   the first track will begin to play.  Ignore that.
3. Above the center-pane (top-right) is the "search" box.
   In there, begin typing the title of the track you want
   -- just until it singles-out in the center pane.

   No.  Case doesn't matter -- but spaces do.
4. Then: left-click the little down-arrow to the right.
5. Hover over "library" -- and left-click on "Songs (1)"
   If it says more than (1) -- that's fine.
6. Now you can drag your preferred one-song from 
   the center-pane to the right pane, and drop it
   (no matter what may be there now).

   Your song will immediately begin to play -- and ditto 
   forever -- if you have the repeat icon (circle-arrow) 
   highlighted in the player controls (bottom-center).

   Enjoy        :)

Answer (score 1):

Also if you have a search result of multiple songs you need to type the match in exactly until all the others disappear and it’ll then loop the greatest match too as well as other choices above.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen. To repeat one song only, you have to have the repeat button on, and then you have to double-click the song you want to repeat from the actual folder the song is in, NOT in WMP.

Comment: This is more suitable for a comment than a true answer. Please refrain from this until your reputation allows you to post comments, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a playlist from your library with the song you wanna repeat.
To do that, clear the playlist then drag the desired song to the empty playlist. Activate repeat.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + t or in play menu check [repeat]

Answer (score -1):

When playing a song, click "Switch to Library" at the upper right corner. then click "Turn repeat on" at the lower part. You can then click "Switch to now playing" at the lower right corner.

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work for me.